# QT After creating a new resource file occur multiple target patterns

Tags: qt, makefile

After creating a new resource file, the following error occurred:
[image]

Now I think the problem is caused by setting UTF8 encoding in cmd. Next, I will continue to try to solve the problem.
I hope to receive answers from the big shots

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I have solved my problem. My actions are as follows:

The file with the default setting of UTF8 encoding will be removed in regedit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).